# Prove that $(\mathcal{F}(E, \mathbb{R}), \|.\|_{\infty})$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f_n$ be Cauchy for the $\|.\|_{\infty}$ norm, meaning we have 
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, \forall p \in \mathbb{N}, \|f_n - f_{n+p}\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon.$$
Since ($\mathbb{R}$, $|.|$) is complete, $f_n$ converges to $f(x)$ for the $|.|$ norm, therefore we have 
$$\forall x \in E \ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists p_x \in \mathbb{N},\forall p \geq p_x, \ |f_p(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$

How do I prove that 
$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N' \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n \geq N', \|f_n-f\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon \ ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that given $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that 
$$
|f_n(x)-f_{n+p}(x)|\le\epsilon\quad\forall x\in E,\quad\forall p\in\mathbb{N}.\tag{1}
$$
You also know $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$. Now let $p\to\infty$ in (1).